# Aligning the ActionBar icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-toolbar

I followed [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer#java) tutorial to create a Navigation Drawer activity. I have the following code:

**Activity XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".Activities.DashboardActivity">

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/login_blue"
    android:theme="@style/MyNavbarTheme" />

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Activity code**

```
....

ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();

try {
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_menu_white);
}
catch (NullPointerException err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}

...
```

However, the menu icon isn't aligned with the text (see image). The icon is slightly above the center. How can I fix this? Also how can I change the color of the title text? [image]

Comment: check this out: [How to make Android Toolbar follow Material Design guidelines](https://medium.com/@lucasurbas/making-android-toolbar-responsive-2627d4e07129)

Comment: Does this happen after you start the activity in landscape and rotate the phone to portrait?

Comment: @EugenPechanec it happens in both modes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to solve this issue.

**I removed this from my code**

```
actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_menu_white);
```

**and used this instead:**

```
 ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
     this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.text_in, 
     R.string.text_out);
 mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
 toggle.syncState();
```